# Lattices and noncommutative algebras in noncommutative geometry

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, lattices, noncommutative-geometry

This a question that I've asked in mathematics stack exchange without having received any response :

I am interested in the relation between lattices and noncommutative algebras in the context of noncommutative geometry. In the commutative case, a lattice is a discrete subgroup of a locally compact abelian group, and it can be associated to a commutative C-algebra via the Pontryagin duality. Is there a similar correspondence in the noncommutative setting? More precisely, can one associate a lattice (or some generalization of it) to a noncommutative C-algebra or a von Neumann algebra? If so, what are the properties of such a lattice and how does it relate to the spectral or topological aspects of the noncommutative space?

I would appreciate any references or examples on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand your claims about the commutative case. You seem to be claiming that given a commutative Cstar algebra, one obtains a lattice. That simply isn't true. Perhaps you are thinking very specifically about the Cstar algebras of locally compact abelian groups, but if that is the case you should say so. (Not every Cstar algebra is a group Cstar algebra, at least not in a natural way)

Comment: To be more explicit: how do you propose to associate a lattice to the Cstar algebra $\ell^\infty/c_0$? or the Cstar algebra $C(K)$ where $K$ is a Klein bottle?

Comment: I think the question need clarification.  What lattice is being associated to a given commutative $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: Here's the stackexchange post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787783/lattices-and-noncommutative-algebras-in-noncommutative-geometry

Answer (score 4):

[Actions, quotients and lattices of locally compact quantum groups by Brannan, Chirvasitu, and Viselter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00227)